# How to write a file to file system in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

How can I write a file to the file system of a computer, using Java? I know how to save a file in a location relative to the location of the compiled program, but I don't know how to save the file in a specified location in the computer.

What would be the simplest way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting absolute paths?

Comment: This is a little too general. Yes, it can be done. ... give a good effort, then return with some code & error messages.

Comment: The simplest way is what suits your need. =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use absolute paths to write to specific locations rather than relative locations. The mechanism depends on whether you choose to use the `java.io` package or `java.nio` package.

Also, I must add, you can get absolute paths for some well-known locations like current directory, user's home directory, etc by using `System.getProperty()` method.

Please have a look at [the tutorials provided](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) to get started. These are `java.nio` tutorials. To quickly show you, you can create an absolute path as such:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\home\\joe\\foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) to give you an idea about how to work with files in Java.